# Issues with arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am fetching some of the datas from my database and one of my column has multiple entries from one user say col(col1) values(a,b,c). Now when I am selecting data from this database, my array looks like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => srt
    [1] => qwe
    [2] => xyz
    [3] => abc
    [4] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => srt
    [1] => qwe
    [2] => xyz
    [3] => abc
    [4] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => srt
    [1] => qwe
    [2] => xyz
    [3] => abc
    [4] => 3
)
```

Now as my array shows only fourth element of array is different.

I want to insert this data into another table which has different columns for different values means only one row corresponding to one user. Thus

col(col1) turns in to col(cola,colb,colc).

Now I want to insert like

cola -> 1,colb -> 2,colc -> 3.

But I am not able to access these values. If I select array[4] then it selects all four elements if I try this **$array=array($result[4]);**  then it create an array of result but with same index value

```
Array ( [0] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 3 ) 
Array ( [0] => 4 )
```

I hope I am able to clarify my question.

So please suggest me some way so that I can access these values in some way.

Thanks !

**EDIT**

**my code**

```
while($result= mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
$array=array($result[4]);

echo "</pre>";
print_r($array);
```

**my result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => suresh.galaxy@gmail.com
    [email] => suresh.galaxy@gmail.com
    [1] => 2011-01-06 13:00:36
    [date_joined] => 2011-01-06 13:00:36
    [2] => 1
    [is_active] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [attribute_id] => 1
    [4] => suresh
    [info] => suresh
)


Array ( [0] => suresh )

Array
(
    [0] => suresh.galaxy@gmail.com
    [email] => suresh.galaxy@gmail.com
    [1] => 2011-01-06 13:00:36
    [date_joined] => 2011-01-06 13:00:36
    [2] => 1
    [is_active] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [attribute_id] => 2
    [4] => patidar
    [info] => patidar
)


Array ( [0] => patidar )

Array
(
    [0] => suresh.galaxy@gmail.com
    [email] => suresh.galaxy@gmail.com
    [1] => 2011-01-06 13:00:36
    [date_joined] => 2011-01-06 13:00:36
    [2] => 1
    [is_active] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [attribute_id] => 4
    [4] => e5c59af60000c8dff51e4e9a315ab152:vN
    [info] => e5c59af60000c8dff51e4e9a315ab152:vN
)


Array ( [0] => e5c59af60000c8dff51e4e9a315ab152:vN )
```

Comment: i have mentioned in my question "If i select array[4] then it selects all four elements if i try this $array=array($result[4]); then it create an array of result but with same index value "

Comment: You mean $array[0][4]? Or in other words $array[LEVEL1][LEVEL2]?

Comment: Can you add additional code to the question? It's hard to understand for me what you're trying

Comment: can you post more actual code? and we can answer from it

Comment: @axel.michel  just $array

Comment: To get these values you need to write $array[0][4]..

Comment: @fedmich I have edit my question please look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a loop first, then from there you could slice the array after the loop

```
<?php
$arr = array();
while($result= mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
$arr[] = $result;

}

print_r($arr);

echo  $arr[0][4] ;
```